# WS02 can't parse json with colon in key

Tags: json, xml, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Using WSO2, I'm having problems parsing Json with a colon in one of the keys.  The value also has commas

For example,

```
{
   "foo:bar" : "a,b,c" 
}
```

I have this json in a property.  I'm using a payloadFactory like this:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
  <format>
      {
        "data" : $1
      }
  </format>
  <args>
     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('json')"/>
  </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

I get error:

```
[2021-03-19 08:54:31,213] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil} - #writeAsJson. Could not convert OMElement to JSON. Invalid XML payload. Error>>> Undeclared namespace prefix "foo"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,447]
[2021-03-19 08:54:31,216] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter} - Error occurred while writing to application/json java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

If I try to put the value in quotes (which is not really the result I want)

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
  <format>
      {
        "data" : "$1"
      }
  </format>
  <args>
     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('json')"/>
  </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

This time I get the error

```
[2021-03-19 09:06:09,045] ERROR {org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl} - Could not get parser from data source for element jsonObject javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.io.IOException: Illegal character: <f>
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:245)
```

Tried specifying `evaluator="json"`.  When using `"data" : $1` (without double-quotes), I get this weird error:

```
[2021-03-19 09:40:52,525] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} - javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[8,23]
Message: Unexpected symbol: COMMA org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[8,23]
Message: Unexpected symbol: COMMA
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
```

which I assume is complaining about the commas in the Json value

Is there any way to do this?

**Update**: I cannot reproduce this using this test sequence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/testMeta" name="TestMeta" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="PUT">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="json-eval($)" name="test" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>
                    {
                    "data" : $1
                    }
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('test')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property description="JSONIFY" name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

However, in my actual code, I faked out the JSON and tried various values.

```
{
   "foo:bar" : "a,b,c" 
}
```

worked, but one of the actual values,

```
{
    "pdf:unmappedUnicodeCharsPerPage":"[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
}
```

does not.  I don't know exactly what triggers it.  Also tried

```
{
    "foo:unmappedUnicodeCharsPerPage":"[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
}
```

to ensure there was nothing special about the string `pdf`

The way I'm faking it out is just hard-coding the value:

```
<payloadFactory description="BuildFinalPayload" media-type="json">
   <format>
   {
     "metadata" : {"foo:unmappedUnicodeCharsPerPage":"[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
   }
  </format>
  <args/>
</payloadFactory>
```

So it doesn't seem to have anything to do with how the value is being loaded into the property

**UPDATE #2**

So I realized that the error is happening right at the end of the sequence, when it's about to exit.  My whole sequence looks something like this

```
<iterate>
  <payloadFactory/>

  <aggregate/>
</iterate>

failure occurs here
<respond/>
```

I can log `json-eval($)` after the payloadFactory and it looks fine

I've got the statement

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json" />
```

at the end, but even if I comment that out, I get the error

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your issue but with the following code but found no errors, I reckon something is off with either your messageType[1] before you put the data into the property or the property is set to be "OM" which will turn it into an XML object. But as this isn't included in your example I can't be sure.

```
  <property expression="json-eval($)" name="test"/>
  <payloadFactory media-type="json">
  <format>
  {
    "data" : $1
  }
  </format>
    <args>
     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('test')"/>
    </args>
  </payloadFactory>
```

As input I used:

```
{
 "foo:bar" : "a,b,c" 
}
```

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-messageType
[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Property+Mediator (Part about TYPE = OM)

Comment: Thanks.  Obviously, that was just sample data and maybe I didn't capture what's triggering the issue.  I thought it was the colon being mis-interpreted as a namespace.  I'll have to come up with a better reproducible example.

Comment: Are you saying if the incoming message is XML, then this won't work?  I thought that WSO2 can move seamlessly between XML and JSON.  Is there a way I can tell what the incoming type is.  Displaying get-property(messageType) returns null.
The property I'm setting is definitely String and not OM

Comment: WSO2 can move relatively seamlessly to JSON but when you first put data into a property it can get a little interesting sometimes. Can you maybe log the property to see what the inside of it looks like?

Comment: Please see update.  Can't reproduce with test code, so there is clearly something about my sequence that is triggering it.  The input is JSON.  When I log the property, it looks fine.  It's a JSON string.  Why is it being interpreted as XML?

Comment: Looking at your code you're putting an Aggregate mediator inside the iterate, an aggregate mediator can't be inside it. Best to change that first before continuing.
Also regarding the evaluator - you're getting an error when setting the evaluator to json because in that case the expression should be jsonpath instead of xpath. (instead of get-property or $ctx: it would be json-eval($.foo) when grabbing from the current context).
Which version of EI are you on?

Comment: I've seen many examples of Iterate/Aggregate and they are inconsistent.  But having the Aggregator does seem to work the way I have it, other than with this case.  I'm running version 6.6.